# ggplot increase border line thickness

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I increase the blue border line thickness? The `stroke` parameter is ignored in my example below.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_col(color = "blue", stroke = 2)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hopefully this works for you:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy,fill="snow")) + 
  geom_bar(color = "navy",size=0.05,stat="identity",alpha=0.3)
```

The result:
[image]

Then changing the size aesthetic:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy,fill="snow")) + 
  geom_bar(color = "navy",size=2,stat="identity",alpha=0.3)
```

Yields this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

`geom_col` does not have a `stroke` argument. Try this:

```
   library(tidyverse)
   ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
   geom_col(color = "blue", size = 2)
```

Comment: Answer still works but receives this warning message ```Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0. Please use `linewidth` instead.```